# Is it a DOS or DDOS if the attacking computers are on the same network

Tags: networking, denial-of-service

I'm currently doing a reflective report (reviewing someone else's work) for uni and the report is about DDOS.

For the report the author carried out a DOS attack on a web server using computers that all belong on the same network (and subnet to my best knowledge). The DOS software used was LOIC.

As the computers all belong on the same network is this technically just a DOS attack or the fact that more than one computer was used in the attack makes this attack a DDOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was both a DOS and a DDOS.  A Denial of Service attack is a broad term encompassing any attack that prevents availability.   A distributed denial of service attack is where more than one source contributes to the attack.

That they are on the same network isn't important.

Comment: thanks Paul, I was struggling to get a concrete answer from searching the Internet

Comment: FYI, the correct acronym for Denial of Service attack is "DoS" (note the lower case 'o').  A DOS attack sounds like a virus that only affects Tandy 1000's.